# How to ensure INSERT INTO wont add the same value on the mySQL DB

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, insert

Is there a way to make an INSERT INTO prepared statement but make sure the name the user will give wont be put on the DB if it already exists?

```
public ServerConn(String sql_name,int sql_year,String sql_ticket)
  {
   try
        {
           Class.forName( "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" ) ;
           java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/promitheas?user=gunner&password=1234") ;
           this.sql_name = sql_name;
           this.sql_year = sql_year;
           this.sql_ticket = sql_ticket;
           PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO tickets (xronia,ticket,name) VALUES (?,?,?)");
           ps.setInt(1,sql_year);
           ps.setString(2,sql_ticket);
           ps.setString(3,sql_name);
           ps.executeUpdate();
           System.out.println("Done!");
   } catch (SQLException case1){
         case1.printStackTrace();
   } catch(Exception case2){
         case2.printStackTrace();
 }
}
```

Comment: Create an unique constraint

Comment: You can easily do this by creating unique constraint on table on name column. If you don't like to do that way, another alternative is through Java (which is not a good option in term of performance). You have to perform select query on table and check if name already exist. If exist then don't add if not then add record.

Comment: This isn't related to your question, but you should use a stored procedure rather than hard code your insert statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check this on the database by adding a unique constraint like this :

```
ALTER TABLE tickets ADD UNIQUE (name)
```

The INSERT won't be possible if the name already exists in the database.

Comment: If you want to make sure your query does not crash because of this restraint, use INSERT IGNORE INTO table. This will irgnore duplicate key errors and simply not insert the violating row.

Answer (score 1):

Make the row unique in the database? If you try to insert identical data you should get a message telling you that the data already present and can not be stored because only unique data can be inserted.

Comment: Please provide OP with more details.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by in different ways.
You could create a [unique constraint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-unique.htm) or you could just write another query to check whether the data already exists in the database:

```
ResultSet rs = query ("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE conditions" + ";");
if (rs.next() )
//it exists in the table already
```

Comment: Ok I declared "name" as unique on my DB. Suppossing I need to print a meesage saying that "Name xxx already exists in table" instead of compiler giving me errors, the message would go in which part of your code?? You may edit your post and write it there

Answer (score 0):

Two choices for resolving it :

- alter the table and add unique constraint on this column
- add some codes before the opertion insert. And the goal of the new codes is to validate the name dosen't exist in the actual table.